# python - count number of windows containing only 0s

Tags: python, arrays

Let's suppose I have a list or array `ts` of length N:

```
ts = [1, 6, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3]
```

Let's suppose `k=4`.

I need to find the number of times that a sequence of `k` or more consecuitve zeros are present in the array. In this case it would be 1 (when a 0-sequence is found, the search must continue starting from the next non-zero item).

Right now I achieved this task with a brute-force, C-like method.

Any idea for a pythonic solution?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code? In what way do you have a "brute-force" solution, what is there to improve over simply iterating the list once!?

Comment: A. The code I have to achieve this task is 60+ lines long. It was not made by me, I got it from a collaborator
B. The aformentioned code runs in O(n^3). I am sure there is a faster way.

Comment: A O(n) solution is trivial to implement, *really* trivial.

Comment: please explain how my entire last comment was counterproductive, I literally served you the solution on a silver platter, all you need to do is write 9 lines of code and end of with the most performant solution. (I still struggle to understand how to complete the assignment in n^3 even if I tried...)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get the groups of identical values and filter the ones who are made of zeros.

To count the ones with length greater than `k`, you can take advantage of the fact that `True` is 1, so all can be done with:

```
from itertools import groupby

ts = [1, 6, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3]
k = 4

nb = sum(len(list(group))>=k for key,group in groupby(ts) if key==0) 

print(nb)
# 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to lists our best friend is usually [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html).
[`goupby`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will give us groups of consecutive equal elements in our list.
Every time `groupby` yields the value in each window, and an iterator for that window.

```
from itertools import groupby


# Define general function
def nice_group(value, group, target_value, min_length):
    return value == target_value and sum(1 for _ in group) >= min_length

# Count how many windows with my needs are there
print(sum(nice_group(val, group, 0, 4) for val, group in groupby(ts)))
```

Notice that the second argument that `groupby` yields is a generator, not a container.
That's why we cannot do `len(group)`.

Answer (score 0):

Building a string of zeros and spaces, then splitting to get the streaks of zeros:

```
ts = [1, 6, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3]
k = 4

s = ''.join(' ' if t else '0' for t in ts)
print(sum(len(z) >= k for z in s.split()))
```

A working regex solution (after seeing alec_djinn's answer):

```
import re

ts = [1, 6, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3]
k = 4

s = ''.join(' ' if t else '0' for t in ts)
print(len(re.findall('0{%d,}' % k, s)))
```

A basic iterator solution:

```
ts = [1, 6, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3]
k = 4

wins = 0
it = iter(ts)
for x in it:
    if not x:
        zeros = 1
        for x in it:
            if x:
                break
            zeros += 1
        if zeros >= k:
            wins += 1
print(wins)
```